# One-sided debounce (Rx)

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'd like to create a "one-sided debounce" where the F event is only passed on when there was no T event for a timespan of n. Any idea on how to solve this?

Marble diagram:

```
In:   (T)      (F)(T)   (F)       (T)     (F)(T)(F)
       |        |.....   |.....    |       |.....|.....
       |             X        |    |            X     |
Out:  (T)                    (F)  (T)                (F)
```

Comment: Is the source order always T-F-T-F? Is the destination order always T-F-T-F?

Comment: Yes, that should be true for the source and definitively must be true for the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that would mostly work (assuming you want to maintain `TFTF` order). I don't see how the `.Sample` helps. This is quite similar to your solution:

```
var result = source.Publish(_source => 
        Observable.Merge(
            _source.Where(b => b),              //unthrottled trues
            _source.Throttle(ts).Where(b => !b) //throttled falses
        )
    )
    .DistinctUntilChanged();                    //To maintain TFTF order
```

The `.Publish` is recommended because you have multiple subscriptions to `source`.

Comment: I guess you're right. If we throttle first and filter for the F later like you do, we no longer need to sample. I also very much appreciate your remark about Publish as I wasn't aware of that (I'm new to Rx). I've read the doc and that does seem the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Just to clarify - the `.Publish` is there because you have multiple subscriptions to `_source`, but only want one subscription to `source`.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up in the meantime is this:

1. Throttle all F items (in the Rx.Net meaning)
2. Use the throttled F's as sampler for sampling the original input
3. Merge that with the T's of the original input
4. Remove unnecessary T's using DistinctUntilChanged

Marple Diagram:

```
In:         (T)      (F)(T)   (F)       (T)     (F)(T)(F)
ThrottleF:            |......   |......          |.....|......
                           (F)       (F)                    (F)
Sample:                    (T)       (F)                    (F)
MergeWithT: (T)         (T)(T)       (F)(T)        (T)      (F)
DistinctUC: (T)                      (F)(T)                 (F)
```

C# Code:

```
var result = source
                .Sample(source
                            .Where(v => !v)
                            .Throttle(n))
                .Merge(source
                            .Where(v => v))
                .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

**Edit:** 
@Shlomo has provided an improved version which is now marked as solution.